# Error on creating MySQL ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'end'

Tags: mysql, sql, database, create-table

If I type this command in the console:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Timelapses` (`ke` varchar(50) NOT NULL,`mid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,`details` longtext,`date` date NOT NULL,`time` timestamp NOT NULL,`end` timestamp NOT NULL,`size` int(11)NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'end'
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?.

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: It seems a bug in version 5.7. 5.7 [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9724a48978c829cc6af4a094555eafd2), 8.0 [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9724a48978c829cc6af4a094555eafd2).

Comment: Check [Bug #75439 :: MySQL 5.7 sql_mode problems breaks replication](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75439).

Comment: This resource might help you: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: More than a bug is the expected behavior in that version.